# Tuples in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, pgfmath

I am learning to use TikZ to draw things in LaTeX. One of the things that TikZ seems to use everywhere for specifying coordinates is a tuple.  For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=70,
     draw=black,fill=white, inner sep=0pt,anchor=lower 
     side,rotate=90,draw=black,
     fill=white, minimum height=2 cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Creates a small isosceles triangle.  Note the use of `(0,0)`.  Let's encapsulate making a triangle as above with the following macro.

```
\newcommand\Tri[3]{ 
  \node[isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=70,
     draw=black,fill=white, inner sep=0pt,anchor=lower 
     side,rotate=90,draw=black,
     fill=white, minimum height={#2} cm] (#1) at #3 {};}
```

Suppose I wanted to define a function that takes in a size and starting coordinate, and draws a "triangle" of triangles such as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tri{a}{1}{(-1,0)}
  \Tri{b}{1}{(1,0)}
  \Tri{c}{1}{(0,1.41)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The simple way to do this is to make a macro `\TriTri`, such that `\TriTri{a}{n}{x}{y}` creates a triangle of triangles, with bottom triangle anchored at `(x,y)`.

```
\newcommand\TriTri[4]{ 
  \Tri{#1}{#2}{(#3,#4)}
  \Tri{#1}{#2}{(#3+2*#2,#4)}
  \Tri{#1}{#2}{(#3+#2,{sqrt(2*#2*#2)})}} %% note #3+#2 = (x1 + x2)/2 
                                         %% the sqrt bit is sqrt(size^2 + size^2)
}
```

I have gotten this to work! But what I would like to do is instead of having `x` and `y` input separately, I would like to have them input as a coordinate pair. I would like to reference the coordinates as `\first,\second`.  So that `\first(x,y) = x`. The desired effect is that

```
$$\first(1,2)$$
```

would be the same as

```
$$1$$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `xparse` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Tri}{m m r()}
 {%
  \node[isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=70,
     draw=black,fill=white, inner sep=0pt,anchor=lower
     side,rotate=90,draw=black,
     fill=white, minimum height=#2cm] (#1) at (#3) {};
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\TriTri{mmr(,u)}
 {%
  \Tri{#1}{#2}(#3,#4)
  \Tri{#1}{#2}(#3+2*#2,#4)
  \Tri{#1}{#2}(#3+#2,{sqrt(2*#2*#2)}) %% note #3+#2 = (x1 + x2)/2
                                      %% the sqrt bit is sqrt(size^2 + size^2)
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\TriTri{a}{3}(2,2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\Tri` command accepts three arguments; the first and the second ones are enclosed in braces, while the third is between parentheses, so

```
\Tri{a}{3}(0,0)
```

In the body of the definition you'll use `(#3)` instead of `#3`, because the parentheses are stripped off.

In the case of `\TriTri` we have to split off the two coordinates, so we define four arguments; the first and the second ones are enclosed in braces; the third is what goes from `(` to a comma, the final one is everything up to `)`.

Thus I have modified accordingly your code for `\TriTri` based on the requirements for `\Tri`.

Comment: Xparse looks great, and I get a feel for how this package works.  However, I have a couple questions:
1) Why do you need to use \NewDocumentCommand?  Is this xparse specific?


2) It seems to drop the braces surrounding a command.  For example, I tried, \NewDocumentCommand{\projL}{r(,u)}{#1}.  And while \projL(1,3) gives the expected 1, \projL{(1,3)} fails to compile.  I like the braced delimiters, and I could parse for them, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @JonathanGallagher With your definition, `\projL` expects to see `\projL(X,Y)` and `X` will be `#1`, while `Y` will be `#2`. If you want a pair of coordinates, use `{r()}` as I did in the definition of `\Tri`. But the parentheses are dropped, you just put them back around `#1`.